# p:InputText prevent pressing enter

Tags: java, ajax, events, input, xhtml

i have a problem with this primefaces component in my view xhtml. I builded a searchbar that filters elements in a list based on the value of this `inputText` component with an ajax call on event. Everything works like it should, till i press enter in inputText, then my filter method does unexpected things. Thats why i tried to avoid pressing enter. But like in the snipped below, the listener isn't called even if `key != 13`.

Does anybody have a idea?

Thanks for your help!

```
<p:inputText value="#{ListView.filter}" style="width:150px" placeholder="Stichwort">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" onevent="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }" listener="#{ListView.filterAvailable}" update="@form"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this  directly on the inputText tag. I usually do this with Internet Explorer.

```
<p:inputText id="testInput" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) return false;" [....]
```

You can simply add a condition in front of it like :

```
<p:inputText id="testInput" onkeydown="#{mySessionInfoBck.ieBrowser ? 'if(event.keyCode==13) return false;' : ''}" [....]
```